# Formatting a date/time in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a datetime field in a SQL Server 2005 table that has values like this:

```
2012-04-23 09:00:00.000
2012-04-23 14:00:00.000
```

The minutes, seconds, and microseconds are always zero.

I need to display a "time slot" (basically, the time plus one hour) like this:

```
2012/04/23  09:00 AM - 10:00 AM
2012/04/23  02:00 PM - 03:00 PM
```

I got what I needed using this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TimeSlot, 20), 1, 10) + '  ' +
       RIGHT('00000' + LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), TimeSlot, 109), 13, 5)), 5) + ' ' +
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TimeSlot, 100),18,2) + ' - ' +
       RIGHT('00000' + LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), DATEADD(hh, 1, TimeSlot), 109), 13, 5)), 5) + ' ' +
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), DATEADD(hh, 1, TimeSlot), 100), 18, 2) AS TimeSlot
FROM MyTable
```

It works, but I feel so dirty.

I know I could do it easier in the code (VB .NET), but assume I have to do it in SQL.

Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the built-in [conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), I would use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    convert(varchar, [TimeSlot], 111) + ' ' +
    RIGHT(convert(varchar, [TimeSlot], 0), 7) + ' - ' +
    RIGHT(convert(varchar, dateadd(hour, 1, [TimeSlot]), 0), 7)
FROM
    [MyTable];
```

this gives you the line you want as

```
2012/04/23  9:00AM - 10:00AM
```

in detail:

- `convert(varchar, @dt, 111)` converts the `datetime` to the Japanese format `yy/mm/dd`
- `convert(varchar, @dt, 0)` converts the `datetime` to `Apr 23 2012  9:00AM` so we can use the time part
- `dateadd(hour, 1, @dt)` adds one hour to the current `datetime` value

you can test it without tables with:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
SET @dt = '2012-04-23 09:00:00'

PRINT convert(varchar, @dt, 111) + ' ' +
      RIGHT(convert(varchar, @dt, 0), 7) + ' - ' +
      RIGHT(convert(varchar, dateadd(hour, 1, @dt), 0), 7);
```

Comment: Thanks...your solution almost gets me there, but more importantly confirms that there isn't a real elegant way to do this.

Comment: normally you just pass the date, then it's your client/server side that handles it giving you a better control of the output and have a function or procedure that can be reused in other areas of your application...

Comment: I agree. I should have clarified, there isn't a real elegant way to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The built in date/time formats in SQL Server will only format to an actual date format, so you're up for custom formatting anyway.  If you're feeding SSRS with this then you might be able to use an expression to format it within SSRS.  Otherwise you're up for formatting it with the query using something like the technique you're describing.

If you're actually displaying it with a VB app then you could do that client-side.

If your date/time values are always on the hour or some consistent interval you could also make a reference table keyed on the time with the formatted interval stored as a varchar column and use that.  That would save you in-lining the formatting expression into every query that needed to produce the interval description.

Answer (score 0):

FollowingConcernedOfTunbridgeW's suggestion, if you maintain a two-column table with a primary key int column [hr] that goes from 0 to 23 and a char(20) column [rng] containing the space-prefixed range string for each hour

```
' 12:00 AM - 01:00 AM'  (in the row where hr = 0)
...

' 11:00 PM - 12:00 AM'  (in the row where hr = 23)
```

this simply query should produce what you want:

```
  select
    convert(char(10),TimeSlot, 111) + rng as TimeRange
  from T join RangesByHr
  on datepart(hour,TimeSlot) = hr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will experiment on Monday.